# Bootstrap 3.2 Navbar gets bigger when scrolling past it

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I scroll all the way down the page, navigation gets bigger.
The navbar is at the top of the code.
I tried putting the navigation at the bottom of the code... It didn't worked...
Can someone please tell me what is the problem?

My code - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoRDk.jpg
The navbar - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzNpf.jpg

Comment: can you create a fiddle (or bootply) to help us diagnose the issue?

Comment: Can you put the code in JSFiddle or similar? It's hard to work with it in Imgur.

Comment: He needs to put his code in his question if anything, and an image of his code doesn't count. You can't adjust their code if it's in an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the attributes `data-spy`, `data-offset-top`, and `data-offset-bottom` from the `nav` tag. The real problem is the `data-offset-bottom` attribute, but the others shouldn't be there either.

**[BOOTPLY DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/VOXZhf5Z0l)**

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

You'll also want to add a bit of padding to the body element, so that your content at the bottom of the page doesn't get stuck behind the nav.

CSS:

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```